# How optimize a lot of different requests to DB?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm using a SQL Server database with EF 6 and LINQ.

For example, I have 10 dropdown lists on a page. And I need to get lists for these dropdown from the database.

I need to do 10 different requests at the same time and it takes a lot of time. Every request takes about 0,05ec in my case. 10 request * 0,05 = 0,5 sec. Very long.

How can I make these requests in another way to improve performance?

Example of request

```
var marriageStatuses = await db.MarriageStatus
                               .AsNoTracking()
                               .Select(x => new
                                            {
                                                Id = x.Id,
                                                Description = x.Description
                                            })
                               .ToListAsync();
```

Example of tables:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Create a List Of Task's and run them all at the same time , they will run on different threads

Comment: You could call them asynchronously in parallel if they don't rely on each other.  Just capture the Tasks and use `Task.WhenAll` to await them all finishing.  Additionally you might want to add caching if the DB data doesn't change often.

Comment: Task task1 =  context.Languages.ToListAsync();
Task task2 =  context.MarriageStatus.ToListAsync();

 await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);  I tried this but got exception - A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

There are some general straightforward techniques to handle issues like this:

1. avoid any n+1 queries by combining them into one query for the the whole set
2. combine any additional queries where redundant data is being fetched
3. lazy-load the components with followup server requests so the page loads first

I might be able to answer more specifically if you had more details like the tables and the columns being queried.

Comment: I added two simple tables from my example.

Comment: Considering how short the tables look, I'm not understanding why there's a performance issue. `0.05ms * 10 = 0.5ms = 0.0005 seconds`?

Comment: Open connection to DB - I think that's why it takes a lot of time and no matter there are 10 record or 100 records. In my case, it takes about 50ms !! for each request.

Comment: If your issue is latency to the database you will only solve it by focusing on that. Either by caching data locally or addressing the network connection.

Comment: Luckily with EF6, you can still access the DbReader through the db context and retrieve multiple result sets in a single query.

Comment: Caching - ok. You are right. About latency - as I know there is always some latency when need to connect to DB. In my case I making 10 different requests and I guess that every time a connection to db creating and closing - that's why I have performance problems.

Comment: @ewqewqewqe If the built in connection pool is working as it should, it shouldn't be opening and closing for every query on the same request.

Comment: It's not the same request. There are 10 different requests in one method.